# Get all Properties with ModelMetadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial class generated from a web service. I add `ModelMetadata` to this class like so:

```
// Automatically generated code

public partial class MyClass
{
    public string FIELD_ONE ...
    public DateTime? FIELD_TWO ...
}

// My code

[MetadataType(typeof(MyMetaDataClass))]
public partial class MyClass
{
}

public class MyMetaDataClass
{
    [Display(Name="Field One")] 
    public string FIELD_ONE;

    [Display(Name="Field Two")] 
    public DateTime? FIELD_TWO;
}
```

Now I would like to get all properties of `MyClass` which have metadata Display Attributes, ie, `FIELD_ONE` and `FIELD_TWO`.

I've tried things like

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayAttribute))
```

But of course the attribute is not on the properties of `MyClass`. I've also tried:

```
ModelMetadata mmd = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => pi.GetValue(m, null), Html.ViewData);
```

But I get the error "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

If I could get from `MyClass` to `MyMetadataClass` I might then be able to get the property names of that and get the properties of the same name from `MyClass`.

Is this possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: check this this out , i already answered this question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757520/3050647

Answer (score 2):

What is it exactly that you are trying to do? If you want to override what the default metadata provider does, then you are probably better off replacing `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` with your own implementation. Here is some example code:

http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/14/creating-your-own-modelmetadataprovider-to-handle-custom-attributes/

Here, the author is adding support for his own custom attributes but you can just as easily override the default implemntation for the `DisplayAttribute`.

if this is not helpful, please give more detail as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In the example I want to be able to iterate through `FIELD_ONE` and `FIELD_TWO` on a 'MyClass' object automatically.